# Limit concurrent Threads in Spring Web Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, threadpool, synchronized

I have a spring Web MVC application which has a Web Method in SOAP called calculateWebMethod.

Because of the number of concurrent requests the server was overloading and my team decided to make the Web Method call a public static synchronized method `CalculateTask` to make the requests run in a single Thread and the overload go into a queue.

So basically we have this scenario:

```
public class CalculateBean {
   public static synchronized long CalculateTask(params...) {
      long result = null;
       ... code to calculate
      return result;
   }
}


@WebMethod(operationName="calculateWebMethod", action="calculateWebMethod")
public calculateWebMethodResponse calculateWebMethod(
   @WebParam(name="param1") String param1,
   @WebParam(name="param2") String param2,
   ...
) {
   ...
   long webMethodResult = CalculateBean.CalculateTask(...params);
   return webMethodResult;
}
```

The problem is the queue is too long to process all the requests in an acceptable time, but leave everything in multiple threads will overload the server, is it possible to limit the number of threads executing `CalculateTask` for 10 or n concurrents setting up this limit on execution time and make the overload go to a queue?

Comment: ‘ setting up this limit on execution time ’ Execution time meaning when the spring app is loaded first time or is parameterized or other way?

Comment: FixedThreadpool or Semaphores should work if thinking of compile time

Comment: It means that the number of threads in the pool, should be changeable without restarting the application. 
Thanks, gonna take a look in FixedThreadpool and Semaphores

Answer (score 2):

when multiple requests are made, that `webmethod` will work be executed in parallels threads , first of all you have to remove `syncronized` form static method.
Now, the problem is large number of concurrent requests can not be handled because of limited resources in the server.
assume that only 10 concurrent requests are allowed, when a request came, if 10 ongoing requests are there , then the expected behavior should be defined (weather it return an error or request is queued. if it is second way, then probably caller get read timeout exceptions).

based on the expected behavior, there are lot of different solution, even you can implement your own solution or existing solution. technically this is called "rate limit" . bucket4j is one implementation you can use.
this is a kind of your own simple soution you can implement (not perfect, you can make it perfect by learning and using inbuilt synchronizers we have in java concurrent package )

1. introduce a field `Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(10)` in your controller class or whatever the class which has `webmethod`

then use this kind of logic in web method

```
if (semaphore.tryAcquire())
{
     try
     {
       // your call to calculate task and return the result
      }
      finally
      {
          semaphore.release();
      }
}
else
{
  //handle or throw error , this is the 11th call while 10 ongoing requests are there 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need is a Thread pool. They were built for that purpose. You can configure how many threads are in the pool and have the pool handle executing calls to your calculator bean. The class you can google is ExecutorService or ThreadPoolExecutor. Below is an example in pseudo/Kotlin/Java. This will work well if you don't need the response in real time. You can have your client code initiate the request the look up the result in a separate call but I don't know your business requirement.

**ExecutorService**

Define a thread pool, the number of threads in the pool and some other basics.

```
private val executorService: ExecutorService = ThreadPoolExecutor(
    1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
)
```

Now inside your controller or web request handler tell the executor to execute your calculator bean code. It will send all those calls to the pools queue and the constrained threads that you've defined will process them.

**Handling requests**

```
    @WebMethod(operationName="calculateWebMethod", action="calculateWebMethod")
public calculateWebMethodResponse calculateWebMethod(
@WebParam(name="param1") String param1,
@WebParam(name="param2") String param2,
...
) {
    executorService.execute {
        long webMethodResult = CalculateBean.CalculateTask(...params);
        return webMethodResult;
    }
}
```